# Refresh cfwindow content

Tags: cfwindow

I have a CFWINDOW which displays multiple drop downs that are binded to respective data fetch methods inside a cfc. However the content pulled by these methods are being updated and created simultaneosly in different page. I want the chae to be reflected in my CFWINDOW each time I show/hide my cfwindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the attribute " refreshOnShow = "false|true"
 in cfwindow tag. It will fetch the latest record of yours.

Comment: <cfwindow name="MyWindow" center="true"
closable="false"
draggable="true"
height="300"
initShow="false"
minHeight="100"
minWidth="200"
modal="false"
**refreshOnShow = "true"**
resizable="true"
title="My Test Window"
width="400">
window contents
</cfwindow>